# Automate acceptance of EULA in servicefabricsdkcommon package on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apt, docker, azure

I need to install the Azure Service Fabric SDK on a linux ubuntu VM automatically.  The installation requires you to accept an EULA.  How would I automate the acceptance of the EULA so it doesn't prompt for this?

Steps:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/servicefabric/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/servicefabric.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install servicefabricsdkcommon
```

The last command requires acceptance of the EULA.

On another post, it appears you could maybe use something like:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y servicefabricsdkcommon
```

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in comments by @Elder_Geek, there appears to be a bug that was fixed to solve this issue and it works, however, when I tried to Dockerize this it didn't work.  does dbconf-set-selections behave differently in Docker that may prevent it from working?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/vsts-agent:ubuntu-16.04-docker-1.11.2-standard
WORKDIR /vsts
RUN sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/servicefabric/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/servicefabric.list' \
&& sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893 \
&& sudo apt-get update -y \
&& sudo apt install debconf-utils
RUN echo "servicefabricsdkcommon servicefabricsdkcommon/accepted-eula-v1 select true" | sudo debconf-set-selections \
&& sudo apt-get -qq -y install servicefabricsdkcommon \
&& sudo /opt/microsoft/sdk/servicefabric/common/sdkcommonsetup.sh
```

The EULA still comes up, if I run the command on my docker host it works fine.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086517/eula-accept-bash-script

Comment: Your exact issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/61) in an 10/4/2016 post by anmolah